# Blobs downloading from azure blob container's folder

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

When I am downloading blobs from Azure:

```
$BlobName = "20171019/fac/file.jpg" 
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Blob $BlobName
```

By using above command I am getting only single file.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName
```

By using this I am getting all blobs from container.

`20171019` is folder name in container,
then sub folder `fac`.

My requirement is to download all blobs from `Fac` folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should use this command `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent` to download Azure storage blobs.

If you want to download all blobs in that container, we can use `foreach` to do it, like this:

```
$RGName = "your resource group name"
$SAName = "your storage account name"
$ConName = "your container name"
$key = "your storage account key"
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -prefix "20171019/fac/" -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
$List = $List.name
foreach ( $l in $list ){
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $l -Container $conname -Context $ctx
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Thank you for Gaurav's suggestion, I add `-perfix` to that script.

Comment: Jason....`Get-AzureStorageBlob` accepts a `-Prefix` parameter. I suggest you change your answer to include that. Then you don't have to list all the blobs. Your command would be `$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Prefix "20171019/fac/" -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx`. This will only give the blobs in `20171019/fac/` folder.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for your suggestion, I had add a `-Perfix` parameter to that script:)

Answer (score 3):

Besides Azure PowerShell, you can also try [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy), which has even better performance.

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/20171019/fac /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /S
```

Comment: This is a very good solution if you are in a linux environment:

azcopy \
    --source https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/abc.txt \
    --destination /mnt/myfiles/abc.txt \
    --source-key <key>