# Download contents of azure blob container to a Linux machine using Get-AzStorageBlobContent

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have some data that resides in a blob container and it is stored in folders. I use `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` to download the contents of the blob as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053583/2253386).

It works fine on Windows whereas on a Linux machine it does not keep the folder structure as it prepend the folder name to those individual file names. I was wondering if `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` is not cross platform or am I am missing something. The version of Azure Powershell that I am using for both windows and linux is 3.8. I had a look through the documentation for any  cross platform compatibility issues for `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` but does not seem to mention anything.

This is what I use to download the contents of the blob in windows.

```
$SAName = "your storage account name"
$ConName = "your container name"
$key = "your storage account key"
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
$List = $List.name
foreach ( $l in $list ){
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $l -Container $conname -Context $ctx
}
```